# Getting response object Nodejs Express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a web app running with nodejs and express. I use ejs as view engine. 

This is my ejs file:

```
    <!DICTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Nodejs Mongodb App</title>

    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<ul>
    <li><span>Title: </span> <div><%= movie.title %></div> </li>
    <li><span>From Year: </span> <div><%= movie.fromYear %></div> </li>
    <li><span>To Year: </span> <div><%= movie.toYear %></div> </li>
    <li><span>Genre: </span> <div><%= movie.genre %></div> </li>
    <li><span>Director: </span> <div><%= movie.genre %></div> </li>
    <li><span>Creator: </span> <div><%= movie.genre %></div> </li>
    <li><span>Number of Episodes: </span> <div><%= movie.genre %></div> </li>
    <li><span>Number of Seasons: </span> <div><%= movie.genre %></div> </li>
    <li><span>Poster URL: </span> <div><%= movie.genre %></div> </li>
    <li><span>Plot: </span> <div><%= movie.plot %></div> </li>


</ul>

<button><a href="/delete" style="text-decoration: none">Delete Record</a></button>

<body>

<script>
console.log(movie);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my route:

```
 app.post('/find', function (req, res, next) {
        var collection = db.collection('movies');
        collection.find({title: req.body.title}).toArray(function (err, result) {
            console.log(result[0]);
            res.render('movie.ejs', {movie: result[0]});
        });

    });
```

The form calling /find:

```
<form action="/find" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="title to search" name="title">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

I want to be able to get "movie" that is sent from routes and store it in an object in client side. How may I do this?
Goal: I want to send back the movie id to server to delete it on click of delete button.

**UPDATE 1**
I am searching the movie by title but when I want to delete it I want to use the ID. So what I need is to parse the response body.But how?

Answer (score 1):

What you can actually do here is:

1) make route which you can use to render your page depending on movie title.

2)create a new route which actually works as rest api endpoint(for getting movie details) and you can ajax request to this endpoint and get details of movie.

You node code:

```
app.get('/movie-render-page/:title', function (req, res, next) {
   res.render('movie.ejs');
});

app.get('/movie/:title', function(req,res,next){
     var collection = db.collection('movies');
    collection.find({title: req.params.title}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        res.status.send(result);
    });

});
```

Your html code:

```
<script>
     //call '/movie/:title' and you can than bind data to html and use it 
</script>
```

Comment: I added the part that calls route /find to my post.So you say instead of /find I should call /movie/:title? But how may I give the search input value to the route as 'title' in client?

Comment: @Miss.Code what i am saying is that is rest api you can make ajax call to /movie/:title api and get list in your javascript. than you can add it to dom using javascript dom manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0):

try passing it as a JSON string to the client then making a variable parsing it to JSON.

---

server

```
res.render('movie.ejs', {
    movie: result[0],
    moviejson: JSON.stringify(result[0])
});
```

---

client

```
<script>
    var movie_object = JSON.parse('<%= moviejson %>');
    console.log(movie_object);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The route you show is a `POST`, it should be a `GET` for displaying your movie data in the browser.
2. I assume you are assigning some sort of ID to each record in your data store? You'll need to put that in the page somewhere.
3. Your button will have to be in a `<form>` in your template.
4. You'll need `JS` to `POST` the movie ID back to a POST route in your app that handles deletion (assuming you want to use AJAX, otherwise just set the method to POST in your form and set the action URL correctly).
5. or use http `DELETE` request to pass id to server ( which is more restful way) to handle deletion.

Comment: The route I put in the post is the one that renders the page not the one for deleting.

Comment: `POST` is not for rendering and should not be the route you use to render the page. That route should be a `GET` and you need a `POST` route for deletion.

Comment: But I have to send form data as POST. Should I redirect user to another path so that I can use GET or something else?

Comment: I'm not going to make any assumptions here, but do you understand the difference between `GET` and `POST` and how they are related on both the client and server side? It sounds like you have them confused. A `GET` route on the server is meant to handle `GET` requests from the client (render the page). A `POST` route on the server is meant to handle `POST` requests from the client (in this case, del a record). You need _both_ an `app.get` to initially render the page to the browser and an `app.post` to handle the form submission from the browser. Is this clear?

Comment: Of course I know the difference! :| Yes. I need both of them.

Comment: So then I'm asking a really dumb question when I wonder why you're trying to render a template in your `app.post`? You should be using that route to delete the record, there is no rendering of any template in a `POST` request. You really need to post more of your code.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. Now you are just repeating your previous comments. I told you OK. Now I will get form data in POST ,do the db tasks,now I want to render the page in GET.HOW?